# Load data on server start up and refresh on regular time interval using spring 3.1

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to spring framework. I would like to pull data from database and set that data in application context. When ever we change data in database according  data should be refresh. Please help me out what would be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh your data in application context on change in the database I have a bad news for you - that's not really possible (or easy and straightforward, at least).

Most of the common databases are passive in a sense that they won't let you to subscribe for specific events (like data update) because this will require some additional IPC between database and subscribed application and this is generally not the main purpose of database.

In any case something like this will be database-specific, so if you **really** want this - it is better to check api docs of your database - there is a chance that you'll find means for doing something like this there. Again, this probably won't be very flexible and robust solution.

In general case you go one of 3 routes:

1. Pull your data from database every time it is needed
2. Pull your data from database every time it is needed but add some cache
3. Implement application-level component that will manage data. When data is requested - it will fetch it from the database if it is missing in cache. When data is updated it will update it both in cache and database.

(1) and (2) are are pretty much your only options if your data can be updated not only from your applications. (3) is a good way if data can only be updated from within your application and if amounts of data are small enough to justify it's caching.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for you response. My requirement is to pull data on server start up setting to application context. So that it will be available to application even if session expire.  I want to create another jobs to refresh application context data